# Disable screen lock when in certain location

Tags: mac, screen-lock

Is there a way to disable the screen lock on my Mac, only when certain conditions are met? I'm looking for a way to have it stop locking when connected my home network (i.e. at home)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/about/)?

> ControlPlane allows you to build configuration profiles, contexts in ControlPlane lingo, for your Mac based on where you are or what you are doing.  ControlPlane determines where you are or what you are doing based on a number of available evidence sources and then automatically reconfigures your Mac based on your preferences.  Evidence sources can include your current location, visible WiFi networks, attached USB devices, running applications and more.

You should be able to build an evidence source, such as being connected to the name (SSID) of your home router, then run an application (like [Caffeine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12)) or a script to prevent/turn off the screen lock.

Comment: `ControlPlane supports 32 and 64bit Intel based Macs running Snow Leopard through Lion.`
So it looks like ML is unsupported.

Comment: @segiddins Yep. It does look like ControlPlane [isn't fully working](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/2012/02/controlplane-and-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/) under ML at present

Comment: Perfect! Works on Mountain Lion too

Comment: ...and Yosemite, and El Capitan. I've been using this for years now and happy